# Open-source character creation engine

Tags: asset-creation, avatar

I'm working on a project which aims to create a 3D character/avatar, given a set of facial parameters (e.g. offset of the eyes, hairstyle or gender of the avatar) (something like Blade & Soul character creation). Currently, I'm looking for an API of an open-source game engine that allow generating a 3D avatar from the input set of facial parameters, then return the front view image of that avatar.

However, as I'm completely ignorant about the game-design community, I couldn't either find any appropriate tools that suit my purpose.

Are there any open-source API (maybe from a game) for 3D character creation, then return the front (or any) view of that avatar, with the input being a set of facial parameters?

Edit: The facial parameters I'm referring to are the parameters responsible for the appearance of the avatar. It can be either continuous (a floating number, e.g. offset of the eyes) or discrete (hairstyle or gender).

Comment: This is not a feature that game engines usually provide. Each game using customizable characters will typically implement their own version of this, specific to their art style, character parameters, rig structure, etc. The closest project I can think of is Unreal's MetaHumans, but this is proprietary and not open source. You might want to think of this less as a single engine/API black box, and more a sequence of steps: 1) get a model with morphable parameters, 2) apply morphs, 3) render that model. You may find free or commercial assets to get you started with point 1.

Comment: Yeah, this stuff is made by game developers, it isn't just a tool in any game engine.

Comment: @DMGregory thanks for your replies. Are there any API of this purpose that you know of?

Comment: @Pow thanks for your replies. Are there any API of this purpose that you know of?

Comment: The thrust of my comment is that thinking of this as one specialized API is likely to hold you back. Look for a 3D character model with configurable features, then you can use any game engine that can load that model. That engine will have its own API for manipulating its blend shapes or bones as needed and rendering it the way you like.

Comment: @K.XGai I'm not sure you're using the right terms, an API allows you to connect different applications together, like a restaurant might have an API to access their menu. It's unlikely you will find an "api" for this purpose and any that you do will likely be paid, as things like things aren't super easy to make.

Comment: @DMGregory can you explain more about "configurable features"? 
What I need is to adjust a morphable model via a set of facial parameters, instead of using mouse/keyboard or any peripherals. Which is why I referred to it as an "API".

Comment: @Pow I'm not sure how I should call it. What I'm thinking of is a tool of any kind, which receives a bunch of parameters, and output a 3D avatar, and even render a view of preferred camera angle.

Comment: @K.XGai Parameters? Like words, or values. Because if you want to be able to tell it the features you want, your talking AI.

Comment: @Pow Sorry for not being clear. The parameters I'm talking about are the facial parameters, something like the offset of the eyes (continuous), or hairstyle (discrete).

Comment: In that case I'll write an answer for the best method I would recommend to achieve an effect like that.

Comment: Questions asking "what tool/software/API should I use" are considered off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

The method I would recommend would be to create models for each thing you want, for example one body, two eyes, different hairstyles, etc.

Then you can use the parameters to do different things. Like you said eye offset. You can just move each eye model a certain amount. Or for hairstyles, you can set the hairstyle you've chosen active, and deactivate all others.

Hopefully this answers your question. :)

Comment: So what I need to do is to manually create a model in Unity, and then attach them to each parameters right?

Comment: Create the full model, in whatever 3D modelling software you use, then split it into individual objects, and mess with each individual object depending on the parameters.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your active helps! However, as I have no knowledge of 3D creation or game design, creating a 3D model is not possible for me :) This is why I wanted to find an "API" or a tool that automatically generates a 3D model from the input parameters. Again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately not. You're best bet would be finding a free model online. But no problem for the help.

Comment: You can't just "move each eye model a certain amount". Eyes go in sockets; if you move the eye without adjusting the shape of the head, it just won't be aligned with the head anymore. Other facial features that are often customizable, such as the nose and ears, are typically part of the head mesh, not separate meshes. Blendshapes are a common way to implement customizable heads/faces.

Comment: It was just a general idea, the way he implements it is up to him. Regardless of what method he uses, it would still be moving the eyes. But I get what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you look at VROID Studio. It is a free program that let's you generate anime style avatars for VR Chat that can be imported into unity. The exported models have blendshapes and bones already rigged, so it should be easy to make sliders for them in Unity. You own the models you generate with VROID but you may not use them for the purpose of creating your own standalone avatar generator program (direct competition with the source program). I am not a lawyer, but using it in the context of a game should be OK.

Link to VROID: https://vroid.com/en/studio